# Objective-C pass block as parameter

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

How can I pass a `Block` to a `Function`/`Method`?

I tried `- (void)someFunc:(__Block)someBlock` with no avail.

ie. What is the *type* for a `Block`?

Comment: A reference that I use more than I care to admit: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/

Answer (score 265, accepted):

The type of a block varies depending on its arguments and its return type. In the general case, block types are declared the same way function pointer types are, but replacing the `*` with a `^`. One way to pass a block to a method is as follows:

```
- (void)iterateWidgets:(void (^)(id, int))iteratorBlock;
```

But as you can see, that's messy. You can instead use a `typedef` to make block types cleaner:

```
typedef void (^ IteratorBlock)(id, int);
```

And then pass that block to a method like so:

```
- (void)iterateWidgets:(IteratorBlock)iteratorBlock;
```

Comment: Why are you passing id as an argument? Is it not possible to easily pass an NSNumber for example? How would that look?

Comment: You can certainly pass a strongly-typed argument such as `NSNumber *` or `std::string&` or anything else you could pass as a function argument. This is just an example. (For a block that's equivalent except for replacing `id` with `NSNumber`, the `typedef` would be `typedef void (^ IteratorWithNumberBlock)(NSNumber *, int);`.)

Comment: This shows method declaration. One trouble with blocks is that the "messy" declaration style does not make it clear and easy to write the actual method call with a real block argument.

Comment: Typedefs not only make the code easier to write, but significantly easier to read since block/function pointer syntax isn't the cleanest.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan, coming from the Swift world but having to touch on some old Objective-C code, how can I tell if a block is escaping or not?  I read that by default, blocks are escaping except if decorated with `NS_NOESCAPE`, but `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` I'm told is non-escaping, yet I don't see `NS_NOESCAPE` anywhere in site, nor is escaping mentioned at all in the Apple docs.  Can you help?

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer when it doesn't show how to pass a block as a parameter to a method? All the answers here show how to declare block parameters, but no one actually ever uses them. Weird.

Answer (score 69):

The easiest explanation for this question is follow these templates:

**1. Block as a method parameter**

***Template***

```
- (void)aMethodWithBlock:(returnType (^)(parameters))blockName {
        // your code
}
```

***Example***

```
-(void) saveWithCompletionBlock: (void (^)(NSArray *elements, NSError *error))completionBlock{
        // your code
}
```

Other use of cases:

**2. Block as a Property**

***Template***

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) returnType (^blockName)(parameters);
```

***Example***

```
@property (nonatomic,copy)void (^completionBlock)(NSArray *array, NSError *error);
```

**3. Block as a method argument**

***Template***

```
[anObject aMethodWithBlock: ^returnType (parameters) {
    // your code
}];
```

***Example***

```
[self saveWithCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
    // your code
}];
```

**4. Block as a local variable**

***Template***

```
returnType (^blockName)(parameters) = ^returnType(parameters) {
    // your code
};
```

***Example***

```
void (^completionBlock) (NSArray *array, NSError *error) = ^void(NSArray *array, NSError *error){
    // your code
};
```

**5. Block as a typedef**

***Template***

```
typedef returnType (^typeName)(parameters);

typeName blockName = ^(parameters) {
    // your code
}
```

***Example***

```
typedef void(^completionBlock)(NSArray *array, NSError *error);

completionBlock didComplete = ^(NSArray *array, NSError *error){
    // your code
};
```

Comment: [self saveWithCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
        // your code
    }]; In this example the return type is ignored because it is void?

Answer (score 52):

This might be helpful:

```
- (void)someFunc:(void(^)(void))someBlock;
```

Comment: you're missing a parenthesis

Comment: This one worked for me while the previous one didn't. Btw thanks mate, that was, indeed, helpful !

Answer (score 22):

You can do like this, passing block as a block parameter:

```
//creating a block named "completion" that will take no arguments and will return void
void(^completion)() = ^() {
    NSLog(@"bbb");
};

//creating a block namd "block" that will take a block as argument and will return void
void(^block)(void(^completion)()) = ^(void(^completion)()) {
    NSLog(@"aaa");
    completion();
};

//invoking block "block" with block "completion" as argument
block(completion);
```

Answer (score 9):

One more way to pass block using с functions in example below. 
I`ve created functions to perform anything in background and on main queue.

blocks.h file

```
void performInBackground(void(^block)(void));
void performOnMainQueue(void(^block)(void));
```

blocks.m file

```
#import "blocks.h"

void performInBackground(void(^block)(void)) {
    if (nil == block) {
        return;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), block);
}

void performOnMainQueue(void(^block)(void)) {
    if (nil == block) {
        return;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
}
```

Than import blocks.h when necessary and invoke it:

```
- (void)loadInBackground {

    performInBackground(^{

        NSLog(@"Loading something in background");
        //loading code

        performOnMainQueue(^{
            //completion hadler code on main queue
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You also can set block as a simple property if it's applicable for you:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^didFinishEditingHandler)(float rating, NSString *reviewString);
```

make sure that block property is "copy"!

and of course you can also use typedef:

```
typedef void (^SimpleBlock)(id);

@property (nonatomic, copy) SimpleBlock someActionHandler;
```

Answer (score 4):

Also you invoke or call a block in using usual c function syntax

```
-(void)iterateWidgets:(IteratorBlock)iteratorBlock{

    iteratorBlock(someId, someInt);
}
```

More info on blocks here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a completionBlock for a class which will return the values of dice after they have been shaken:

1. Define typedef with returnType (`.h` above `@interface` declaration)

   ```
   typedef void (^CompleteDiceRolling)(NSInteger diceValue);
   ```
2. Define a `@property` for the block (`.h`)

   ```
   @property (copy, nonatomic) CompleteDiceRolling completeDiceRolling;
   ```
3. Define a method with `finishBlock` (`.h`)

   ```
   - (void)getDiceValueAfterSpin:(void (^)(NSInteger diceValue))finishBlock;
   ```
4. Insert previous defined method in `.m` file and commit `finishBlock` to `@property` defined before

   ```
   - (void)getDiceValueAfterSpin:(void (^)(NSInteger diceValue))finishBlock{
       self.completeDiceRolling = finishBlock;
   }
   ```
5. To trigger `completionBlock` pass predefined variableType to it 
   (Don't forget to check whether the `completionBlock` exists)

   ```
   if( self.completeDiceRolling ){
       self.completeDiceRolling(self.dieValue);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the answers given on this thread, I really struggled to write a function which would take a Block as a function - and with a parameter.  Eventually, here's the solution I came up with.

I wanted to write a generic function, `loadJSONthread`, which would take the URL of a JSON Web Service, load some JSON data from this URL on a background thread, then return an NSArray* of results back to the calling function.

Basically, I wanted to keep all the background-thread complexity hidden away in a generic reuseable function.

Here's how I would call this function:

```
NSString* WebServiceURL = @"http://www.inorthwind.com/Service1.svc/getAllCustomers";

[JSONHelper loadJSONthread:WebServiceURL onLoadedData:^(NSArray *results) {

    //  Finished loading the JSON data
    NSLog(@"Loaded %lu rows.", (unsigned long)results.count);

    //  Iterate through our array of Company records, and create/update the records in our SQLite database
    for (NSDictionary *oneCompany in results)
    {
        //  Do something with this Company record (eg store it in our SQLite database)
    }

} ];
```

...and this is the bit I struggled with: how to declare it, and how to get it to call the Block function once the data was loaded, and pass the `Block` an NSArray* of records loaded:

```
+(void)loadJSONthread:(NSString*)urlString onLoadedData:(void (^)(NSArray*))onLoadedData
{
    __block NSArray* results = nil;

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        // Call an external function to load the JSON data 
        NSDictionary * dictionary = [JSONHelper loadJSONDataFromURL:urlString];
        results = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Results"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // This code gets run on the main thread when the JSON has loaded
            onLoadedData(results);

        });
    });
}
```

This StackOverflow question concerns how to call functions, passing a Block as a parameter, so I've simplified the code above, and not included the `loadJSONDataFromURL` function.

But, if you are interested, you can find a copy of this JSON loading function on this blog:
http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/Services/WebServices-Page6.htm

Hope this helps some other XCode developers !
(Don't forget to vote up this question and my answer, if it does !)

Comment: This is seriously one of the best tricks I've seen for ios and blocks.  Love it man!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The full template looks like

```
- (void) main {
    //Call
    [self someMethodWithSuccessBlock:^{[self successMethod];}
                    withFailureBlock:^(NSError * error) {[self failureMethod:error];}];
}

//Definition
- (void) someMethodWithSuccessBlock:(void (^) (void))successBlock
                   withFailureBlock:(void (^) (NSError*))failureBlock {
    
    //Execute a block
    successBlock();
    failureBlock([[NSError alloc]init]);
}

- (void) successMethod {
}

- (void) failureMethod:(NSError*) error {
}
```