# How to call second function after first function excecution completed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, function

I have 3 function in my code.
The code i did for manage queue for function execution.

```
 [self firstMethodWithOnComplete:^{
    [self SecongMethodWithOnComplete:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(CallThirdMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
            });
    }];
}];
```

First And Second Function

```
- (void)firstMethodWithOnComplete:(void (^)(void))onComplete {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    //processing here.....

    [self CallFirstMethod];
    onComplete();
});
 }

- (void)SecongMethodWithOnComplete:(void (^)(void))onComplete {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    //processing here.....
    [self CallSecondMethod];
    onComplete();
});
 }
```

The problem is  i am unable to manage their execution. I want execution order such in a way that second function only execute if first is over and third execute if second execution over.
Please help me to solve this or give any appropriate suggestions.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            
            NSLog(@"dail image : %@",self.imageUrl);
            
            self.imgAppIcon.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageUrl]]];
            
        });
    });

Comment: you can try like this

Comment: Have a read of this article:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936570/objective-c-pass-block-as-parameter/27379471#27379471   It shows how to call a function (loading data from a website) which then calls a second function once it's finished.  It shows how to pass a function as a parameter.  This should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dispatch groups for this kind of requirement, Below i am posting example code which i have used

```
__block NSError *configError = nil;
__block NSError *preferenceError = nil;

// Create the dispatch group
dispatch_group_t serviceGroup = dispatch_group_create();


dispatch_group_enter(serviceGroup);
 // Start the first async service
dispatch_group_leave(serviceGroup);


dispatch_group_enter(serviceGroup);
// Start the second  async service
dispatch_group_leave(serviceGroup);

dispatch_group_notify(serviceGroup,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    //Update UI in this block of code
});
```

Comment: what is self.configService and self.preferenceService stands for.?

Comment: its just an example func block i have made , u replace ur code in that

Comment: implementation of above code give me this error==>  DB Error: database is locked

Comment: DB operation sud be done on one thread not many , OR main thread

Comment: DB operation are in both method i.e first and second so how can i put it into thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106984/discussion-between-mitesh-dobareeya-and-muku).